# Electrolytic capacitor function for noise filter

Tags: microcontroller, filter, noise

I have a 2-wire endstop that gets a lot of noise (the cable is together with other stepper motor cables) and a lot of noise enters it for a 3.3V microcontroller (I measured it with an oscilloscope.)

Someone recommended this circuit, I think that with an RC filter it would be enough but in addition to that he added a 1uF electrolytic capacitor.  What function does this capacitor perform?

[image]

Comment: Bulk decoupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 capacitors are necessary if you are trying to reduce as much noise as possible. Although the non-polarized one might look useless considering how small it is, the function isn't to add more capacitance; it's there to impede noise at frequencies the electrolytic cap cannot absorb.

For a much more detailed explanation, check out this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WytU5uj78-4&ab_channel=Afrotechmods

Answer (score 1):

The 100nF (0.1µF) capacitor alone would work for less-noisy environments.

I think the 1µF was suggested simply as more bulk capacitance, so the circuit would function in even noisier areas.

Generally, capacitors under 1µF are non-polarized, and are also not electrolytic type, while capacitors over 1µF are likely polarized, and may or may not be [electrolytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor) type.

So the fact that the 1µF is an electrolytic type specifically (as opposed to tantalum, ceramic, or any other type), is totally irrelevant to this circuit. You could also get 1µF by adding 10 more pieces of the 100nF. What is important, is that if the capacitor is polarized, it must not be connected backwards - they tend to explode if connected in reverse.